# AngularJS Getting results of service promise to bind to directive value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

In my view I have the following directive:

```
<line-chart data="buildData(id)" options="buildOptions(id)" />
```

In my controller I have:

```
var onGetData = function (response) {
  return response.data;
}

$scope.buildData = function(id) {
  dataService.getDataById(id).then(onGetData);
}
```

In my directive I have:

```
function lineChartLink($http){
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    chart.bindData(scope.data);
  }
}
```

Now, my issue is, how do I get the line-chart directive the data it needs?

Comment: The line-chart propably has an ngModel attribute? You should define it there and assign the data you receive to that particular $scope variable then.

Comment: Can you explain with some pseudo code? I'm following in theory, but don't have enough experience with directives and scope inheritance to do it.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You're showing us the code of getData and onGetData, which are completely irrelevant, since you call buildData and buildOptions to pass arguments to the directive.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized the typo and fixed my question. The controller should've been $scope.buildData

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make a choice here.

If you want to pass data to the directive, then you shouldn't invoke the directive until the data is available. You can do that pretty easily with a simple `ng-if`:

```
$scope.buildData = function(id) {
    dataService.getDataById(id).then(function(response) {
        $scope.data = response.data
    });
};
$scope.buildData(someId);
```

and in the view:

```
<line-chart ng-if="data" data="data" ... />
```

Or you can pass a promise to the directive, and the directive should call `then()` on the promise to get the data when available:

```
var onGetData = function (response) {
    return response.data;
};

$scope.buildData = function(id) {
    // note the return here. Your function must return something: 
    // the promise of data
    return dataService.getDataById(id).then(onGetData);
};

function lineChartLink($http){
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.data.then(function(theActualData) {
            chart.bindData(theActualData);
        });
    };
}
```

and in the view:

```
<line-chart data="buildData(id)" ... >
```

Or, third solution, you can pass the id to the directive rather than the data, and let the directive get the data by itself.